# How to remove a css class and add another when I get a certain mobile resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using boostrap grid and is working perfect I just got a issue with col-xs-6 when I get the resolution 375px, `col-xs-6` by standard come with 50% and I know I can just create a media query and change it for 100% and will fix my problem.

I just don't want do that kinda hack :), it's any way to remove the class col-xs-6 and add col-xs-12 when get 375px?

I know can just change it for col-xs-12 of course but that will change my div when I get 667px because xs is for extra small resolutions.

In jquery or even better in bootstrap?

My classes:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 no-padding sidebar-container"> </div>
```

How it should look afterwards:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 no-padding sidebar-container"> </div>
```

Comment: "I just don't want do that kinda hack :)," — That isn't a hack. Using media queries to restyle content at different screen sizes is what media queries are for. The hack would be trying to change the classes that an element is a member of based on the screen size.

Comment: you don't have to blindly follow media queries widths from bootstrap. If you need layout to change on 375px and 667px just change the media queries - this is clean solution.

Comment: Yes I could do, but the thing is the senior developer here don't like these kinda things so that reason I asked for the solution in other way because he said well col-xs-6 is col-xs-6 so we should not change that size. :)

Comment: other thing is he does not want another variable in sass :)  we have these 4: 
$screen-xs-min: 320px;
$screen-sm-min: 768px;
$screen-md-min: 992px;
$screen-lg-min: 1200px;

Comment: Then explain to the senior developer the correct way to do this and do it. If he is truly a senior developer, he will understand and accept your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all using media queries is not a hack its a way to change the website layout according to different screens.

But may be because of some reason if you don't want to use it or want to change the class only then you can do it by simple jquery resize function.

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
function sidebarWidth(){
  if(winWidth>375px){
    $('.sidebar-container').removeClass('col-xs-12');
    $('.sidebar-container').addClass('col-xs-6');
  } else {
    $('.sidebar-container').removeClass('col-xs-6');
    $('.sidebar-container').addClass('col-xs-12');
  };
};

sidebarWidth();

$(document).resize(function(){
  sidebarWidth();
});
```

> Above code will run on window load and will detect the screen and add the needfull class. But i am also using the same function in resize function because this will work if you resize the window after load.

Comment: In some browsers this will be extremely inefficient because the resize event is called for every frame rendered during a resize action that the size of the screen changes.
EG: If you resize from 1920 to 1024 the method will be called 896 times in under a second.

Comment: That we all know that resize function will work so many times i a second but 1) If we need to do something which is possible with resize function only then we will do it like that only. if a function exists then it exists because it has a use. 2) In this situation using resize function is totally optional weather you want to play with the classes on screen on load only or on screen resize also. And if we need to do it on screen resize also then using resize function is not bad. **We decide which function to use according to our situations**

Comment: to be fair my layout is fluid, i just fix this on mobile in the handset not if someone resize the browser.

Comment: Then don't use the resize function and problem solved :)